# Approximation of $\int_{0}^{1} {x^{x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find approximation of $\int_{0}^{1} {x^{x}}dx$, with error
>   $\leq10^{-6}$.

The hint is using Taylor's expansion. But http://www.wolframalpha.com/ shows no standard expansion or integral formula... How do I solve problems like this?

Comment: Taylor expansion is a local approximation. you should use trapezoidal or Simpson's method.

Comment: [*Sophomore's dream*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html) has a very rapidly converging series expansion.

Comment: i would get a Taylor series for f(1 + h), where log(1) = 0 of course.  First question - do you know how to differentiate $x^x$ ?  then it should be ok to get a taylor expansion f(1 + h), so then you will have a expansion that you can rebase back to zero, and integrate - i am hoping

Comment: @SangchulLee how to get (8) from (7) in your link?

Comment: By applying integration by parts recursively, you can check that $$\int_0^1 (-\log x)^n x^{s-1} \, dx \stackrel{x=e^{-t}}{=} \int_0^{\infty} t^n e^{-st}\, dt = \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: There's fastly converging series.  Please refer to [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148661/how-to-show-that-frac-pi5-leq-int-01-xx-dx-leq-frac-pi4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that

$$x^x=e^{x\ln x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x\ln x)^n}{n!}$$

Then notice that

$$\int_0^1(x\ln x)^n\ dx=(-1)^n(n+1)^{-(n+1)}n!$$

And thus,

$$\int_0^1x^x\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}n^{-n}$$

Thus is famously known as the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).